# Add extensions to file names using shell

Tags: shell, unix

I have these files:

```
image01
landscape.jpg
.
.
macro01
macro02
```

I want to write a shell script that verifies if the file has any extension; if not it will add the `jpg` extension.

Comment: "I want to write a shell script that verify if the file has any extension if not it will add the jpg one." The world's your oyster, go for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in "$@"
do
    case "$file" in
    *.*) : Already has an extension;;
    *)   mv "$file" "$file.jpg";;
    esac
done
```

If you want to detect `.jpg` as the extension, change `*.*` to `*.jpg` (and fix the commentary in the colon command).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do, is check if the file has `.jpg` extension, else add the extension as required.
Try doing something similar to this:

```
if [[ $file =~ \.jpg$ ]]; then
  echo "has jpg ext";
else
   echo "no jpg ext";
fi;
```

Edit: If you want to handle multiple extensions, then see `Jonathan Leffler's` answer.